# listview disappeared after setState({ds})

Tags: ios, listview, react-native

I am confused with the rerender mechanism of listview.

[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqa4W.png) have render a listview with two item, then I click 'Add' button, navigate to another page, and add one item to Page 1's datasource, then navigator back.

What I expect to see is Page 1 with three item, but actually is [Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Xnp.png), listview is disappeared. But if I use mouse/finger touch it, listView come out again with three item.
I have test it on my iphone and simulator

Page 1's source code:

```
class Market extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 }),
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.refreshListView(this.props.data)
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.refreshListView(nextProps.data)
} 

refreshListView() {
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data)
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this._renderRow}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl/>
      }
    />
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = createSelector(
  selectData(),
  (data) => ({
    data,
  })
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Market)
```

Comment: Im having a similar problem - are you using react-native `0.31.0`? I think it might be a bug as my app was working fine before the update

Comment: @David I'm using 0.30.0, I have not test it on 0.31.0, maybe I should test it on version < 0.30.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found something that has fixed mine! try adding `removeClippedSubviews={false}` to your `ListView`

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8607#issuecomment-231371923